# huge amount of +~JF****.tmp files in /var/cache/tomcat7/temp

Tags: tomcat7, java-7, tmp

In my tomcat temp folder, I have 2.5Gb of `+~JF****.tmp` files, the file sizes are either ~750K or ~23M

```
$ pwd
/var/cache/tomcat7/temp
$ ls -lt
-rw------- 1 tomcat tomcat 23278008 06:47  5 Th08 +~JF2247741302721424357.tmp
-rw------- 1 tomcat tomcat   773236 06:47  5 Th08 +~JF2626850872018060030.tmp
-rw------- 1 tomcat tomcat   750984 06:47  5 Th08 +~JF6955350201064404318.tmp
-rw------- 1 tomcat tomcat 23278008 06:34  5 Th08 +~JF5760450811263657816.tmp
...
```

I did you searching for this problem but all I found is about Jasper Report font problem which doesn't make sense to me, my project is not using Jasper.

do you have any idea why?

thanks

Comment: It's not jasper but java.awt.Font.createFont which does this. So maybe you are using a Font somewhere else.

Comment: thanks, I found out that one of the library I'm using did this by creating fonts

Answer (score 3):

We are facing a similar problem and I would like to share what I found:

`java.awt.Font.createFont(int i, java.io.InputStream in)` generates a temporary file with a name `+~XXXX.tmp` (where XXXX is a long number).

When the JVM ends, all these files are deleted.

The problem arises when the JVM ends abruptly, as it doesn't delete temporary files, or for long-running JVM (i.e.: Tomcat production server).

What we did was just change the font creation method and use:

`java.awt.Font.createFont(int i, java.io.File f)`

With this method a temporary file is not created anymore.